# NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure

Tags: rest, maven, jboss, jax-rs, resteasy

I am getting the following error..
org.jboss.resteasy.core.NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure: Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: "Service Class" of media type: application/json.

But i have already included

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.8.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

I have read that i can add @XmlRootElement , but i think it should work if the above dependency is included in POM ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.7.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#Built_in_JAXB_providers):

> A JAXB Provider is selected by RESTEasy when a parameter or return
>   type is an object that is annotated with JAXB annotations (such as
>   @XmlRootEntity or @XmlType) or if the type is a JAXBElement.

So you either add the mentioned annotations or you choose a JSON-serializer which does not need JAXB-annotations like e.g. Jackson. Then you should add following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.8.Final</version>
</dependency>
```